# Redirecting ffmpeg output to a file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I Want to make a script that using ffmpeg looks for errors in files.
But I can't redirect the output of ffmpeg to a file, it always displays errors in the console.
my script:

```
@echo off
set LOGFILE=error_check.log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit /B

:LOG
for /r %%A IN (*.mp4) DO (
    echo "%%A"
    ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel auto -v error -i "%%A" -f null - 
)
exit
```

I tried redirecting the output of ffmpeg using ">>", but that didn't work either.
I also tried using the option -report together with -loglevel error in ffmpeg, but it outputs way too much I only want error information.

Comment: `>` is an abbreviation for `1>`, which redirects STDOUT. errors usually are printed to STDERR, which is stream 2. To redirect STDERR use `2>`, to redirect both, use `1>nul 2>&1` (STDOUT to .., STDERR to wherever STDOUT is redirected to)

Comment: Thank you for your help, this solved the issue.
Can you write this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` is an abbreviation for `1>`, which redirects STDOUT.

Errors usually are printed to STDERR, which is stream 2. To redirect STDERR, use `2>`.

To redirect both, use `1>... 2>&1` (STDOUT to ..., STDERR to wherever STDOUT is redirected to)

A fully detailed description is available at [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)